# React Native call navigator inside child navigator screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a main navigator  in app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Constans } from './src/constants/Constant';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import { EventScreen } from './src/screens/EventScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
      }
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignupScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerLeft:()=>false,
        headerTitle:()=> (
          <Image style={{width:35,height:35}} source={Constans.logoImage}/>
        )
      }
    },
    Event:{
      screen:EventScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerLeft:()=>false,
        headerTitle:()=> (
          <Image style={{width:35,height:35}} source={Constans.logoImage}/>
        )
      }
    }
  },
  
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

and when I go HomeScreen I have also menu navigator.

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { TabEventsScreen } from './TabEventsScreen';
import { TabForYouScreen } from './TabForYouScreen';
import { TabProfileScreen } from './TabProfileScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
                screenOptions=
                {
                    ({ route }) => 
                    (
                        {
                            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => 
                            {
                                return  <Icon 
                                            name={route.name === 'Explore' ? "globe" : route.name === 'Profile' ? 'user' : route.name === 'Wallet' ? 'money' :'star'} 
                                            size={focused ? 32: 24} 
                                            color={color} />;
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                tabBarOptions=
                {
                    {
                        activeTintColor: '#1F7A8C',
                        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                    }
                }>
                <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={TabEventsScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="For You" component={TabForYouScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Wallet" component={TabProfileScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={TabProfileScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

in one tab screen I am trying to navigate Event screen of main navigator. How can I do it?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Constans } from './../constants/Constant';
import { View, ImageBackground, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { TabEventsScreenStyle } from './../styles/TabEventsScreenStyle';
import { IncomingEvents } from './../services/TabEventsService';
import { EventCard } from './../components/Eventcard'
export function TabEventsScreen({navigation}) {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    _getEvents = () => {
        return IncomingEvents(1, page, 20);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setEvents(_getEvents().Events);
    });
    _OnButtonPress=(key)=>{
        console.log(navigation)
        navigation.navigate('Event',{itemId:key});   
    }
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <ImageBackground source={Constans.homeBackGroundImage} style={TabEventsScreenStyle.backgroundImage} >

                <Text style={TabEventsScreenStyle.title}>Incoming Events</Text>
                <View>
                    {
                        events.map(el =>
                            <Text style={TabEventsScreenStyle.text} onPress={()=> this._OnButtonPress(el.key)}>
                                <EventCard   key={el.key} data={el}></EventCard>
                            </Text>
                        )
                    }
                </View>

            </ImageBackground>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

my error is

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload
> {"name":"Event","params":{"itemId":1}} was not handled by any
> navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'Event'?
>
> If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see
> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

I also tried

```
const parent_nav=navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
        console.log(navigation);
        parent_nav.navigate('Event',{itemId:key});
```

but `parent_nav` is undefined

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate as if all screens were at the same level.

> Navigation actions are handled by current navigator and bubble up if couldn't be handled
>
> For example, if you're calling navigation.goBack() in a nested screen, it'll only go back in the parent navigator if you're already on the first screen of the navigator. Other actions such as navigate work similarly, i.e. navigation will happen in the nested navigator and if the nested navigator couldn't handle it, then the parent navigator will try to handle it. In the above example, when calling navigate('Messages'), inside Feed screen, the nested tab navigator will handle it, but if you call navigate('Settings'), the parent stack navigator will handle it.

The [source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigation-actions-are-handled-by-current-navigator-and-bubble-up-if-couldnt-be-handled).

When you navigate, it will try to find your screen in the current navigation and if it failed, then will try with the parent until the root navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your AppContainer with NavigationContainer instead of the TabNavigator, so that both the StackNavigator and TabNavigator use the same navigation prop

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <NavigationContainer>
              <AppContainer />
         <NavigationContainer/>
      )}
   }
```

And remove NavigationContainer from the TabNavigator

Here is how I nested Stack and Tab Navigator

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, StatusBar, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AScreen from './AScreen';
import BScreen from './BScreen';
import CScreen from './CScreen';
import DScreen from './DScreen';
import A from './a';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';
import D from './D';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const BottomTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      activeColor="#ff6362"
      backBehavior="initialRoute"
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#000000'}}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="A"
        component={AScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'A',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="book-open" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="B"
        component={BScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'B',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="people" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="C"
        component={CScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'C',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="people" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="D"
        component={DScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'D',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="person-pin" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default function AdminScreen(props) {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
          <Stack.Screen name="BottomTab" component={BottomTab} />
          <Stack.Screen name="A" component={A} />
          <Stack.Screen name="B" component={B} />
          <Stack.Screen name="C" component={C} />
          <Stack.Screen name="D" component={D} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Worst case scenario you can pass the navigation prop of the StackNavigator as context inside the tab navigator, I guess